# Indexing Bilingual Sites

Tags: search, indexing

I have a site that supports two languages. The way the user changes the language is by clicking on a language link that will change his session language from A to B and return him to the same page. The problem that I am facing is that Google doesn't index the other language since it is seeing that the language link is the same as the page link but with changes in the parameters.

So is there a way to inform google of the language, or should I add the language in the url, i.e. www.example.com/A/home?

Answer (score 0):

I think that a good option is to embed the language inside the url like

```
www.example.com/en/
www.example.com/de/
www.example.com/fr/
etc.
```

you can also use subdomains like `en.example.com` but it should be more complex to handle.

Of course you should provide your index page `www.example.com` all the links to open the sublanguages pages..

Comment: hmm,

So there is no way for session based indexing, right?

If this is the case then I have no solution but to manually put the language id in the url, so long friendly urls :(